# Nodejs stripe api without frontend

Tags: node.js, flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to build NodeJs stripe api on which I don't want front end. Because I want to pass credit card info manually (Because I want to use this on my Flutter app) So maybe you will say why I am not using flutter stripe plugin its because on Flutter stripe plugin I can't use my customise form.

So what I just want to know is that is it possible or not to connect NodeJs Stripe without using stripe frontend.

I have create a start point where ill get id but I am confuse for next step and not find anything for custom fields

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express()

const Stripe = require('stripe');

const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc');


app.get("/charge", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
            {
                amount: 100,
                currency: "USD",
                payment_method_types: ["card"],
                receipt_email: "suda@gmail.com",
            },
            function (err, paymentIntent) {
                if (err) {

                    res.send(err);

                }
                res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(paymentIntent));

            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err, "error occure");
    }
});




app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server is running on port 3000')
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try to pass data like the amount, payment method etc... inside the headers of your request ? Then you'll send this request whenever you click on the button to send the payment.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own client integration and still use NodeJS in your server.  But keep in mind that you will need to be [responsible for PCI Compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance). Using flutter_stripe will get you PCI compliant automatically, and you can still [customize your form](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example) I highly suggest taking a look into the repo's examples.

For the question of the next step, generally you have done creating a PaymentIntent on your server. You will need to collect your customer's card data on your client, and confirm that PaymentIntent. I suggest to look at the [full guide here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements). You can choose NodeJS as your server language[image]

Comment: @orkaro I'm sort in the same scenario  bus I'm not sure about the whole process. As the question above from my server I send back to the Client a created PaymentIntent. So far so good. Now in my my Flutter app I'm trying to use the `flutter_stripe` but looking at the example app I only get more and more confused.. it's using  this `final url = Uri.parse('$kApiUrl/charge-card-off-session');`to  post an http request with the body `body: json.encode({'paymentIntentId': paymentIntentId})`.. where that URL comes from? Why use a package to end up making http requests? Thanks